# iPod Touch 2g not recognised by iTunes (more information inside)

Tags: windows, windows-vista, itunes, ipod-touch, itunes-10

My iPod Touch isn't being recognised by iTunes.

Details: iPod Touch: 2nd generation / Laptop: Windows Vista / iTunes: latest version

- I have tried: using different cables;
- restarted my laptop and iPod.
- reinstalled iTunes.
- restarting services that were made by Apple;
- putting my iPod into restore mode;
- resetting my iPod; and still no luck getting it to be recognised by iTunes.
- This iPod works on other computers, and different iPod's work on my laptop.
- When I stopped all of the Apple services on my laptop, I got a message from iTunes when I connected my iPod saying that I needed to enable the services for it to work. But when I did enable the services again, the iPod still didn't show up on iTunes.

I can't think what else I can do to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There are support articles on the apple website that cover this problem.

Comment: Thank's for the advice, but I have been through the Apple website and tried all the support articles I could find that relate to this issue. If there is a specific one you suggest I look at then feel free to link to it!